# Galois group of $\prod_{i=1}^{p-1} (X^2-i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime. How do I compute the Galois group of $F/Z_p$ where $F$ is the splitting field of $\prod_{i=1}^{p-1} (X^2-i)$ over $Z_p$?

Since exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ integers from $1\leq i\leq p-1$ are the roots of $X^2-i$ in $Z_p$, let's write $F=Z_p(\sqrt{i_1},...,\sqrt{i_k})$ where $k=\frac{p-1}{2}$ and $\sqrt{i_j} \notin Z_p$.

This leads me to guess that the Galois group is $(Z_2)^k$, but is it really true? How do I prove this?

Comment: The notation [$\mathrm{F}_p$ is preferred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) ($Z_p$ means the $p$-adic integers)

Comment: Edited the title to match the question body as well as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that for any non-squares $x$ and $y$ of $Z_p$, there is some $a\in Z_p$ such that $x=a^2y$. In this way, once you adjoin to the field the square root of one of such elements, you have adjoin the square root of all the other roots. In other words,
$$Z_p(\sqrt{i_1},\ldots,\sqrt{i_k})=Z_p(\sqrt{i_l})$$
for any $l$. Hence $F/Z_p$ is cuadratic and the Galois group is just $Z_2$.